# Swagger OpenAPI use object with schema instead of array

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm using `L5 Swagger` from `DarkOnLine` to generate Swagger docs using OpenApi schematics.

To use schema I can do

```
@OA\Property(property="certification", type="array", @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Certification"))
```

and it works perfectly fine and shows as

```
"certification": [
    {
      "certification_id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
```

. But it creates an array block with square brackets with multiple objects inside it.

How do I use the same working but lose the array. Something like

```
@OA\Property(property="certification", type="object", @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Certification")),
```

so as to remove square brackets and show only object like.

```
"certification": {
      "certification_id": 0,
      "name": "string"
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do:

```
@OA\Property(
  property="certification", 
  ref="#/components/schemas/Certification"
)
```

The `@OA\Items` annotation is only used when you want to specify what are the properties inside an array (see [Data Types: array](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#array)).

In your case you just want to describe an object so you just have to reference the object's schema in the property and remove `@OA\Items`.

Answer (score 0):

You can define sub-properties like this:

```
@OA\Schema(
   schema="MySchema",
   type="object",
   @OA\Property(property="MyObject",type="object",
      @OA\Property(property="sub_prop1",type="string",example="active"),
      @OA\Property(property="value",type="integer",example="3"),
   ),
)
```

or by using

```
@OA\Schema(
   schema="MySchema",
   type="object",
   $ref: '#/components/schemas/MyObject'
)
```